# Any way to get chat messages MIME using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

Any way to get chat messages MIME using Microsoft Graph API. I know this is in BETA, but anyone knows any way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not currently supported for teams, as it is supported for mail messages using $value endpoint